# java строку перевести в дату

Tags: java

Дату получаю в виде строки `"Wed Feb 10 10:57:32 Восточноевропейское время 2016"`, её надо перевести в формат `10.02.2000`.

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("EEEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzzz yyyy", Locale.getDefault()
```

Когда пишу:

```
formats.parse("Wed Feb 10 10:57:32 Восточноевропейское время 2016")
```

то выводит ошибку :

> Unparseable date: "Wed Feb 10 10:54:27 Восточноевропейское время 2016"
>   (at offset 0)

Comment: если грамотно по-русски напишите вопрос, у вас будет больше шансов получить грамотный русский ответ.

Comment: Возможно, у вас лишняя `E` в самом начале. И локаль лучше указать явно, ибо текст на русском `new Locale("ru")`

Comment: на облаке дата лежит в таком формате 2016-02-10T08:38:20.803Z

Comment: Подебажил чутка. Проблема в том, что дата записана частично в английской локали, частично в русской.
Если указывать `SimpleDateFormat("EEEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzzz yyyy", Locale.forLanguageTag("ru")`, то парсер ломается на дне недели, ибо в русской локали он ожидает увидеть `Ср`, а не `Wed`. Если же указать английскую, то парсер ломается на `"Восточноевропейское время"`.

Comment: и как решить данную проблему?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Переношу в ответ из комментариев, так как тут можно код читабельный кидать:

Подебажил чутка. Проблема в том, что дата записана частично в английской локали, частично в русской. Если указывать `SimpleDateFormat("EEEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzzz yyyy", Locale.forLanguageTag("ru")`, то парсер ломается на дне недели, ибо в русской локали он ожидает увидеть `Ср`, а не `Wed`. Если же указать английскую, то парсер ломается на "Восточноевропейское время".

Из того что я выяснил, нам нужно чтобы `DateFormatSymbols` были для английского языка, кроме `zoneStrings`. Набросал такой код, который вроде бы должен делать то, что нужно, но у меня почему-то `dfsRu.getZoneStrings()` возвращает всё равно для английского языка строки, хотя в классе `sun.util.resources.cldr.ru.TimeZoneNames_ru` лежит то, что нам нужно. Почему он достает английский для русской локали я пока не понял.

```
    String s = "Wed Feb 10 10:57:32 Восточноевропейское время 2016";
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzzz yyyy");
    DateFormatSymbols dfs = DateFormatSymbols.getInstance(Locale.forLanguageTag("en"));
    DateFormatSymbols dfsRu = DateFormatSymbols.getInstance(Locale.forLanguageTag("ru-RU"));
    dfs.setZoneStrings(dfsRu.getZoneStrings());
    sdf.setDateFormatSymbols(dfs);
    Date date = sdf.parse(s);
    System.out.println(date);
```

Comment: Походу, надо явно ВМ [указывать провайдера](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/intl/enhancements.8.html) типа `java.locale.providers=CLDR,JRE`, правда у меня тогда даже в английской локали `parse` работать перестает...